# What is this tall plant or weed? (with photos)

Tags: identification, weeds

What is this plant / weed? [see photos below]

It's about 6+ feet tall now, though I'm guessing most people don't let them grow this tall.

This is growing currently (August, 2020) in northwest Ohio.

[image: tall weed]

[image: close-up of plant]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a stinging nettle (*Urtica dioica*), be careful not to touch it. It can sting you and that will burn and itch very bad.

It is not native to your area, it is an invasive species.

If you have a lot and you think they grow on clean soil, you can consume them as tea or soup. Of course wear gloves when harvesting them.

Comment: Touching it is actually a pretty quick and accurate way to identify the stuff; just painful.